# hsqldb migration from 1.7.3 to 2.3.4 - Username and password were not case sensitive in hsqldb-1.7.3.jar

Tags: java, hsqldb

While creating a ConnectionURL in hsqldb v1.7.3 Username and password were not case sensitive but in v2.3.4 it is case sensitive. I am migrating fro 1.7.3 to 2.3.4, so can anyone please help me with any property i can set while creating the DB or while connecting to the DB which can allow me to connect the DB without case sensitive username and password.

Comment: Can't you convert the entered username and password to uppercase when you open the connection?

Comment: yes, i can convert username to uppercase but it will have to include a lot of jars in HF and also it would include lot of testing as well. I would prefer to set in HSQLDB to accept username and password in both cases.

Comment: You will need a lot of testing anyway if you upgrade from 1.7.3. There are quite a lot of differences in versions 2.3.x.

Comment: Fred, i am still facing few problem, Can you please guide me with below problems i posted in answer section since word limit doesn't allow me to post here?